# RecursiveAction thread pool size

Tags: java, concurrency, fork-join, forkjoinpool

I just saw a use for the Java 7 RecursiveAction.invokeAll(), and I wonder:

What is the size of the threadpool of tasks? (or the algorithm which determines it..)

If I have a lot of tasks (say 100 tasks), should I use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of the thread pool is whatever you set it to be, either the number of cores that you have:

> public ForkJoinPool()
>
> Creates a `ForkJoinPool` with parallelism equal to `Runtime.availableProcessors()`, using the default thread factory, no `UncaughtExceptionHandler`, and non-async LIFO processing mode.

Or some specific number:

> public ForkJoinPool(int parallelism)
>
> Creates a `ForkJoinPool` with the indicated parallelism level, the default thread factory, no `UncaughtExceptionHandler`, and non-async LIFO processing mode.

Please read [the JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html) for more information.

The way a recursive action works is that it spawns multiple versions of itself. You always start with **1**. The number of actions generated is somewhat immaterial, hundreds or thousands should be fine - as long as they don't "pile up".